# Python3: Relative import beyond toplevel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

Yes, there are similar questions, but they do not answer my issue. My directory structure is as follows, *all __init__.py files are blank*.

```
Package/
    __init__.py
    sub_package1/
           __init__.py
           file1.py
    sub_package2/
            __init__.py
            file2.py
```

In `file2.py` I have the following code:

```
from ..sub_package1 import file1
```

I get the error mentioned above,

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

There are a number of scikit-learn packages which do similar imports and it works for them.

Command that raised the error:

1. working directory: `Package/`
2. Command: `python /path/to/Package/sub_package2/file2.py`

Comment: Could you include "what command" raised the exception?

Comment: added the command raising the error.

Comment: The duplicate I've linked is a different exception, but the same solution (also the same solution that @Jean-Paul has answered below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not relative imports work depends on how you invoke the code, unfortunately.

```
$ mkdir Package Package/sub_package{1,2} 
$ touch Package/__init__.py Package/sub_package{1,2}/__init__.py
$ touch Package/sub_package1/file1.py
$ echo "from ..sub_package1 import file1" > Package/sub_package2/file2.py

$ python Package/sub_package2/file2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Package/sub_package2/file2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..sub_package1 import file1
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

$ python -m Package.sub_package2.file2
$
```

When you `python Package/sub_package2/file2.py` the runtime doesn't recognize that `Package/sub_package2` is part of the module path.  It thinks the module you're working with is just `file2`.  So it cannot interpret the `..` relative import.

When you import the module using its full path, as `python -m ...` does (and as any normal import statement will do), the full import path is recognized and relative imports can be interpreted properly.

Comment: I get the error (beyond top-level): ```ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package```, and not the "non-package"

Comment: I'm not sure the particular text of the exception matters much.  It's true you're encountering a slightly different error path than I demonstrated.  However, the underlying cause of both errors is the same.  Use of a source file which is meant to be a sub-package as though it were a top-level script.  If you avoid that then you'll be safe from this class of errors.